# Runtime error 0xC0000005 - access violation

Tags: c++, boost, access-violation

i have an intresting issue with objects behaviour in C++.
I have a code like this(it's simplified code):

```
    class Example
    {
     public:
      void SetA(const int& na) {a = na;}
     private:
      int a;
    }
    class Example1
    {
     public:
      Example& GetExample() {return a;}
     private:
      Example a;
    }
    class Example2
    {
     public:
      Example1& GetExample1() {return a;}
     private:
      Example1 a;
    }

    template<
    class Object,
    class Setter = void(__thiscall Object::*)(const int&)>
    class ExampleSetter
    {
     public:
      ExampleSetter(Object& parameters, Setter setter):
       m_setter(setter), m_params(parameters)

      void ApplySet(int toSet)
      {   
       boost::bind(m_setter, boost::ref(m_value), toSet)();
      }
     private:
      Object& m_value;
      Setter m_setter;
    }

    int main()
    {
     // all Example%n% classes have proper constructors and properly initializes all fields
     Example2 example(...); 
     ExampleSetter<Example> setter(example.GetExample1().GetExample(), &Example::SetA);

     for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
     example = Example2(...);
     setter.ApplySet(i);
     }
    }
```

I getting writing access violation in SetA when calling assignment operator. This error appears randomly (on 5-6 iteration) when i running app in Release mode without debugging and always appears on 1-st iteration when i debugging in Release mode. In debug mode the error disappear =). All Example%n% objects are defined in .dll and ExampleSetter - in .exe. So i have no clue why this happening. Сould anybody help me please?

UPD:
 Class "Example" have a lot of other fields. This error appears randomly, so i got error after some other simular calls of other setters finished correctly.

Comment: Does your dll persist through application lifetime or gets unloaded some time?

Comment: Can you please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Something which we could copy & paste into e.g. ideone or coliru and see the error ourselves. Or, if it's not reproducible in that environment, at least something which reproduces the error for you and *compiles.* Your code misses several `;`, uses undeclared identifiers (`m_params`) etc. Regardring the "extra fields" - verify that it's reproducible without them. If not, *include them in the question.*

Comment: Since this is just a vague approximation of your actual code, all one can say is that you have undefined behaviour, and that it's caused by something, somewhere. My first guess would be that you're referencing an object which has ceased to exist.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that adress of variable could change after assigning (i just log adresses of Example::a before "example = Example2(...);" and after. They can be different). Question closed, thanks a lot.